# PIctureBox placement is misaligned during runtime

Tags: c#, winforms, runtime, parent-child, picturebox

I have a Windows Form application, and in the designer, everything has been lined up the way I intended to have it. (I've circled the troublesome component, though the other components also seem shifted, this one is the important one.)

This is the view in designer mode.
[Designer View http://pokestory.tm14.net/_articleimages/misalign1.png](http://pokestory.tm14.net/_articleimages/misalign1.png)

I compile, I run, and I end up with something similar, but with misalignment.

This is it during runtime.
[Runtime View http://pokestory.tm14.net/_articleimages/misalign2.png](http://pokestory.tm14.net/_articleimages/misalign2.png)

I don't understand why this is happening and I was wondering if anyone could shed any light on this.

Oh, this *might* have something to do with it, but I don't see why it would. It's the latest change to the code that might have influenced it to do this, but I don't understand how it would. Still, I'll provide the code.

```
// add the auxilary pictureboxes as a component of the bg picture box to enable transparency
pictureBoxBattleBG.Controls.Add(panelOppPokemon);
pictureBoxBattleBG.Controls.Add(panelPokemon);
pictureBoxBattleBG.Controls.Add(pictureBoxOppPokemon);
pictureBoxBattleBG.Controls.Add(pictureBoxPokemon);
pictureBoxBattleBG.Controls.Add(pictureBoxTime);

// do the same with the time overlay
pictureBoxTime.Controls.Add(pictureBoxTimeOfDay);
```

Comment: Try to move the `00:00 PM` box out of the underneath one and every other, so they wuoldn't overleap each other. To see where is the problem

Comment: Check the `Anchor` property of that picturebox. It should be Left+Top selected.

Comment: The label isn't messing up, but that's probably because I'm not setting it as a child of the bigger control. Also, the default Anchor property is Top, Left, and I haven't messed with it.